# Android personal organizer with notificationi?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-alarms, android-calendar

I am making a personal organizer app in android. One of the feature of it is calendars in day and week view inside the app. Users are able to add events in the app which are stored in a databse. users can set up reminders for events. When a reminder is fired it will bring up a dialog containg event details and some buttons. Furthermore when a user modifies an event or modifies a reminder the notification needs to be updated as well.
How should I go about implementing this? What should I use? I think I will also need to know when a reminder is fired which event fired it.